# Pointer without a cast?

Tags: c

I just started C so this question might be silly.
    Any thoughts on why i keep getting this compilation warning?

Question: Write a function `escape(s,t)` that converts characters like newline and tab into
visible escape sequences like `\n` and `\t` as it copies the string `t` to `s`.

```
3-2.c:37:11: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
3-2.c:38:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
3-2.c:42:11: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
3-2.c:43:9: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

This is the code:

```
int get_line (char input[], int max_size);
void escape(char s[], char t[]);

main () {
    int length, l, i;
char line[MAX], t[MAX];

while ((length = get_line (line, MAX))  > 0)
    escape (line, t);       
    printf ("%s", t);


} 


int get_line (char input[], int max_size) {
    int i, c;
for (i = 0; i < max_size-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    input[i] = c;

if (c == '\n') {
    input[i] = c;
    ++i;
}
input[i] = '\0';
return i;
}

void escape(char s[], char t[]) {
int i;
for (i= 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    switch(s[i]) {

    case '\t' :
                    //This is where i get the warning.
        t[i++] = "\\";
        t[i] = "t";
        break;
    case '\n' :
        t[i++] = "\\";
        t[i] = "n";

    default :
        t[i] = s[i];
        break;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Say `t[i++] = '\\';` etc.

Comment: Also `input[i] = (char)c;` in `get_line()`.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek!!
PS trojonfoe casting apparently wasn't required. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @the_lost_one The cast is not necessary but good practice. It means "I actually know what I'm doing here, trying to store an int into a char". While `input[i] = c` means: "either I know what I'm doing and this is fine, or I don't know what I'm doing and this is a latent bug".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t[i] gives you the char element, 
    t[i] = "t" , t[i++] = "\" assigns the address of the string to the char element

you need to assign with single quotes ' '.

t[i] ='t'; or t[i] = '\';

Answer (score 0):

`t` is char array means t[i] will give you a char element but in line

`t[i++] = "\\";` and `t[i] = "t";`

you are pushing string in these element.Strings are known as array of character not a single character.Something written in `" "` is known as string.By making above mentioned assignment you are passing address of string(pointer).

Answer (score 0):

A `"\\"` or `"t"` literal is a string literal which evaluates to its address in read-only memory.

What you probably want is `'\\'` resp. `'t'` which evauates to that exact character code (0x5C / 92 in ASCII)